# BadHttpRequestException caused by slow clients are showing up in my application insights

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, swashbuckle

One caller of my API sometimes has some performance issues where they max out at 100% CPU on their end and my API is rejecting some of their calls due to request timeouts (HTTP 408). This is fine for me as I consider it protection to reject the calls. However, it also triggers alerts in Application Insights because the timeout is being tracked as an exception. The requests are POSTs.

What can I do to prevent this? I looked into filtering configuration for Application Insights, but I was unable to find anything that would allow me to filter this specific exception. I don't want to filter too many log entries just because of this.

Also, I can see Swashbuckle in the Stacktrace. Could it help to rearrange something in my `ConfigureServices` method? Swashbuckle is currently configured after `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry`.

I use ASP.NET Core 2.2, running on .NET 4.7.2. Application Insights is added via *Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore*

Exception details:

```
Message          Reading the request body timed out due to data arriving too slowly. See MinRequestBodyDataRate.    
Exception type   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException   
Failed method    Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware+<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException:
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException.Throw (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1MessageBody+<PumpAsync>d__4.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException (System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult (System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult (System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody+<ReadAsync>d__27.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream+<ReadAsyncInternal>d__21.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream+<ReadAsync>d__35.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.StreamHelperExtensions+<DrainAsync>d__3.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonInputFormatter+<ReadRequestBodyAsync>d__17.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder+<BindModelAsync>d__7.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder+<BindModelAsync>d__11.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider+<>c__DisplayClass0_0+<<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>d__13.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__23.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__18.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeAsync>d__16.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware+<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware+<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext (Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4232c99127b3c254)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext (Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=62657d7474907593)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware+<Invoke>d__13.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol+<ProcessRequests>d__185`1.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter this type of exception `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException"`, you can use [ITelemetryProcessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#filtering-itelemetryprocessor).

In you .net core project, add a class named `MyTelemetryProcessor`, and the following is the details of this class:

```
public class MyTelemetryProcessor: ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

    public MyTelemetryProcessor(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        this.Next = next;
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {

        ExceptionTelemetry err1 = telemetry as ExceptionTelemetry;

        //you can use exception type or the error message to filter
        if(err1 !=null && err1.Exception.GetType().ToString().Contains("the exception type you want to filter"))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (err1 == null)
        {
            this.Next.Process(telemetry);

        }

        if (err1 != null)
        {
            this.Next.Process(err1);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the Startup.cs -> ConfigureServices() method, add the following code:

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<MyTelemetryProcessor>();
```